# Java imports not working - Ubuntu Eclipse OpenJDK

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, mariadb

I'm using eclipse with OpenJDK 11 on Ubuntu 18.04. It's like my mariadb-java-client-2.5.3.jar can't be accessed, but I really think it should be. I put the jar in a folder lib and added it to the build path.

In fact it seems no imports are working anywhere.

Anyone got any ideas what is going wrong here?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

 public class DatabaseConnector {

     private static Connection connection = null;

     public static Connection connect() {

         try {
             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/DB?user=bob&password=EO750FAS7F6Tvpzx");

         } catch (SQLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return connection;
     }

     public static void disconnect() {
         if (connection != null) {
            try {
                 connection.close();
             } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
     }

 }
```

[image: eclipse view of problem]

I've started on the login file, and again imports are not working

[image: imports not working]

Comment: What is the content of your `module-info.java`? My guess is that you haven't added the necessary modules using a `requires` statement.

Comment: I was just considering that the module-info.java file might be a problem. In fact I don't even know what it is for. I seem to recall i have deleted it in the past. I'm going to Google what it is for right now.

Comment: It is for creating modular Java applications, which requires you to explicitly declare which parts of the java runtime (and other libraries) you depend on. This in turn allows you to create 'minimal' application deployments excluding parts of the Java runtime library you don't use (+ some other benefits). I haven't used it myself yet, though.

Comment: in the module-info.java

    requires java.sql;
    requires java.desktop;

problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are doing the right thing here. I guess you need to change your maria-db-client jar or look into how to import the jar file into your project. I can also see that your imports are not fixed as well. Here is a link to maven repository to download the latest version of maria-db-client:[mariadb](http://%20https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mariadb.jdbc/mariadb-java-client)

Here are the steps on how to add *jar* files to your project in Eclipse:

- Create a folder called lib in your project folder.
- Copy your jar file to the lib folder.
- Refresh your project in eclipse.
- Select the jar file, then right click on it and select Build Path -> Add to Build Path.

I hope this help you and good luck coding.

Cheers.

Comment: The problem is with importing classes from the  `java.sql` package, not only with the mariadb driver itself.

Comment: I dont think that assumption is true. I have similar implementations and it works. I suggest you take a close look at your implementations.

Comment: The OP confirmed that adding the necessary requires statements to his module-info.java fixes the problem, which shows that problem wasn't with the mariadb driver itself. Maybe you are thinking of non-modular Java code, but even there your answer wouldn't explain the problem of importing code from the `java.sql` package (which is part of the Java Runtime library).